# Strange black mark against washing machine wiring harness

Tags: electrical, washing-machine

My washing machine stopped working and I can see that the front panel circuit board has scorch mark on it. I'm thinking about getting a second hand circuit board to replace it but wanted to check some thing before I waste my time and money.
I also noticed the following black marks (see image) against the machine where the wiring harness touches the machine. Notice also the black dust around the inside of the machine? Is this just some bacteria or burn marks. The wires themselves seem fine.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Unplug the machine and then remove the twist ties around the wires and inspect each wire for breaks in  the insulation near where the burn mark is.

Answer (score 1):

With the machine unplugged take those wires out of the wire ties, when whatever went up in smoke the wiring also got overheated and may have shorted, or even been the cause if the wires rubbed through and shorted out.

Closely inspect all of the wires as the insulation may have melted enough to allow conductors to short to each other or ground.